# What is the correct HTTP method for a create or update action in a Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating an API which will be accessed in JavaScript. I want the user of the API to be able to send a request and create_or_update a record in the database. Should I be using the POST, PUT, or PATCH method for this request?

Is the following acceptable or is it outside of REST best practices?

```
# POST /objects
def create_or_update
  object = Object.find_or_create_by(params[:attribute])
  if object.update_attributes(object_params)
    render :json => {}, :status => :ok
  else
    render :json => {}, :status => :bad_request
  end
end
```

Comment: Your implementation only seems to perform `update`. If your question is only about "which HTTP verb to use", that's covered pretty well below.

Comment: Oops, updated, PUT is looking like what I need though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, most appropriate would be PUT. See [HTTP 1.1, section  **4.3.4 PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), which is a "create or replace".